# App has dynamic JS files, unable to debug in Safari Remote Web Inspector

Tags: safari, xmlhttprequest, sapui5, safari-web-inspector

I have a sapui5 app that I'm trying to test on mobile Safari using remote web inspector.  Since it loads javascript files dynamically (uses MVC), it only lists these files under XHR. Apparently, because it's XHR, I can't add a breakpoint to these files.

Is there any way for me to debug this? Or force web inspector to load these files some place else? It seems a bit useless otherwise.

I have the latest version of iOS and Safari on my iPad.

I know this question has been asked previously but nobody answered it.  So I'm hoping this one will gain a bit more traction.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try adding `?sap-ui-debug=true` at the end of your path (but before any hashes), maybe it will serve the files differently

Comment: Unfortunately, that just causes it not to display those files that would be put under xhr. I can't imagine Apple actually intended for this design?  It makes the remote web inspector seem impractical.

Comment: This seems similar to the bug described here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141389

If not, please file a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com/. If so, please add your own steps to reproduce. A reduced test page would be really helpful, as the existing bug does not address breakpoints not working.

Comment: @BrianBurg Pretty much the same bug but I was unable to add breakpoints.  At the time, it was only showing these files in the "XHR" folder with no copy in "Extra Scripts".  This seems to be resolved.  It's very confusing seeing the same JS file in two places--especially when one of them is unusable.

Comment: Did you get this working? For me the files are not showing up in "Extra Scripts". If i reload the page using the reload button in the web inspector, sometimes the folder does appear but it only contains the index.html file..

Comment: @t0PPy I just checked and I don't get the "Extra Scripts" folder either. I can't do it since I'm responding to you but tag Brian Burg in your next comment--he might be able to give some insight